# Duplicate entries of ENUM in two COM components

Tags: c++, visual-c++, import, mfc, atlcom

I am using two ATL/COM component in my VC++ application with the help of following import statement.

```
#import "First.dll"  raw_interfaces_only, raw_native_types, no_namespace, named_guids
#import "Second.dll"    raw_interfaces_only named_guids no_namespace no_implementation
```

First.DLL and Second.DLL have a few repeated declarations. For example, the following enum is declared in both imported DLL files.

```
enum Collection
 {
    JAN,
    SEPT,
    DEC
 }
```

I want to use both DLL but am getting an error like Collection is declared twice.
Can someone please guide me to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disambiguate between types of the same name by moving them into distinct namespaces. To do so, remove the [no_namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/no-namespace) attribute. If the types aren't declared in a namespace already, you can use the [rename_namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/rename-namespace) attribute in the [#import directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-import-directive-cpp).

As an alternative, you can [rename](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/rename-hash-import) one or both of the colliding type names. This allows you to keep the `no_namespace` attribute, and import all types into the global namespace.